# MailChimp 'Generate Code' Button Missing in Pop-up Form Editor

Tags: mailchimp

I'm making a pop-up form in Mailchimp on a free account.

I've followed this tutorial - and it works up to a point:
https://mailchimp.com/help/add-a-pop-up-signup-form-to-your-website/

It says 'In the pop-up form editor, click Generate Code' - there is no Generate Code button (see screenshot):

I've looked in every tab. Without that Generate Code button I can see no way to get the form. Google turns up nothing at all about this.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Any progress with this yet?